# Want to save BufferedImage as jpg but my code saves it as textfile

Tags: java, image, jpeg

I want to export a BufferedImage as jpg, but in this code it will get saved as a textfile. How can i fix this?

```
    public void saveImage(BufferedImage im) {
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("jpg", ".jpg");
    fc.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
    fc.setFileFilter(filter);
    int ret = fc.showSaveDialog(null);
    File f = fc.getSelectedFile();

    if (ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

        try {

            ImageIO.write(im, "jpg", f);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `"jpg"` may not be a valid image format name; `"jpeg"` is used in the documentation.  I'd try: `ImageIO.write(im, "jpeg", f);`

Comment: doesnt work there is the same problem as before

Comment: What is the picture of?  How do you validate that the output is a text file?  Did you open it with notepad and a graphics program?  You can open a jpg file with notepad, but that does not mean it was saved as a text file.

Comment: Its a function that will start if a Button is clicked. The picture is a BufferedImage and I dont know where I validate the output. @ProgrammersBlock

Comment: How did you determine that the output file was a text file?

Comment: I save it in directory and then I see that it is saved as textfile and not as jpg. The .jpg is missing and thats the reason it doesnt work @ProgrammersBlock

Comment: Are you typing in the filename, like "ABC", and then expecting the JFileChooser to return a file with name of "ABC.jpg"?

Comment: Yes thats the function i want to have! @ProgrammersBlock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not an option on JFileChooser to have it autopopulate the extension if not typed in.  You have to check for this after the File is retrieved from the dialog.

```
public static void saveImage(BufferedImage im) {
  JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
  FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("jpg", ".jpg");
  fc.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
  fc.setFileFilter(filter);
  int ret = fc.showSaveDialog(null);
  File f = fc.getSelectedFile();

  if (ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

    try {
      if(!f.getName().endsWith(".jpg"))
      {
        String name = f.getAbsolutePath() + ".jpg";
        f = new File( name );
      }

      ImageIO.write(im, "jpg", f);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
}
```